# need to convert no_of_mobile to integer format

Tags: python-2.7

## need to convert "no_of_mobile" variable to integer format and print using loop

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request =  requests.get("https://priceraja.com/mobile/brands/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request,"html.parser")
mspec = soup.find('ul', attrs = {"class","top-brands"})
list=[]
no_of_mobile=[]
for link in mspec.find_all('li'):
    li=link.getText('li')
    lit =str(li).split("\n")
    litt=lit
    no_of_mobile= litt[1].replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    print no_of_mobile
```

Comment: can you [edit] your question? it's really unclear.

Comment: need to convert all the no_of_mobile to integer format and print only few top integer using loop

Comment: can you [edit] your question with that information ? comment is for us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, 
If you want brand name also, you should modify code where you are parsing the html file and print accordingly.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request =  requests.get("https://priceraja.com/mobile/brands/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request,"html.parser")
mspec = soup.find('ul', attrs = {"class","top-brands"})
list=[]
no_of_mob=[] ## Note the change in list name
for link in mspec.find_all('li'):
    li=link.getText('li')
    lit =str(li).split("\n")
    litt=lit
    no_of_mobile= litt[1].replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    no_of_mob.append(int(no_of_mobile)) ## appending the values to the list, here type of the object is string.
no_of_mob=sorted(set(no_of_mob), key=lambda x:int(x),reverse=True) ## sorting the converted integer values
print no_of_mob[:5] ## printing top 5 (Highest no of mobiles)
```

Comment: @nishantkumar Okay then.. Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark in answer